# To conclude whether two simultaneous equations are solvable for all values in a certain range

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The simultaneous equations in $x,y$, $$(\cos\theta)x-(\sin\theta)y=2\\(\sin\theta)x+(\cos\theta)y=1$$ are solvable
>
> (a) for all values of $\theta$ in the range $0\le\theta<2\pi$;
> (b) except for one value of $\theta$ in the range $0\le\theta<2\pi$;
> (c) except for two values of $\theta$ in the range $0\le\theta<2\pi$;
> (d) except for three values of $\theta$ in the range $0\le\theta<2\pi$.

Solution:

> We will write $c=\cos\theta$ and $s=\sin\theta$ for ease of notation. Eliminating $y$ from the simultaneous equations $$cx-sy=2,\quad sx+cy=1;$$ we get $$2c+s=c(cx-sy)+s(sx+cy)=\left(c^2+s^2\right)x=x$$ and similarly eliminating x we find $$c-2s=(-s)(cx-sy)+c(sx+cy)=\left(s^2+c^2\right)y=y.$$
>
> Hence the equations are solvable for any value of $\theta$. The answer is (a).

How is it possible to know that $\left(s^2 + c^2\right)x = x$ and $\left(s^2 + c^2\right)y = y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Proof of Pythagoras and consequential trig identity by picture alone.

With words:

By Pythagoras' Theorem for a right triangle with hypotenuse of unit length so that hypotenuse makes angle $\theta$ with the horizontal, $s^2+c^2=1$, where $s=\sin(\theta)$ and $c=\cos(\theta)$.

---

This is equivalent to proving Pythagoras' Theorem (see my previous solution), which is now proved by taking moments about a fish tank filled with water and with a  right triangular cross section wrt its orthocentre.  The water inside exerts forces on the inner walls of area $a,b,c$ so that:

$$ a\frac{a}{2}+b\frac{b}{2}=c\frac{c}{2}.$$
i.e. $$c^2=a^2+b^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

I remembered the trigonometric identity now. Obviously true for all values since $$\sin^2(v) + \cos^2(v) = 1$$ Thus $\left(C^2 + S^2\right)x = x$ and $\left(C^2 + S^2\right)y = y$.